# SQL Server file format

Tags: sql-server

I want to ask that if I create a database in a pc and after that I want to transfer it to another pc then is it necessary that SQL Server is installed on that pc also? or I can make a formate of db that can run on any pc like exe file etc?

Comment: Well, I suppose you *could* make a program that reads the database file, but I wonder why you would go through the trouble

Comment: If you want to use SQL Server data - you have to have a SQL Server instance running *somewhere* - on that remote local PC, or on a central server machine that this other PC can connect to.

Answer (score 3):

No, the files created by Microsoft SQL Server can only be used by another (running) instance of SQL Server. You can however embedd a stripped down version of the SQL Server engine into your .exe

Check out the Microsoft website for "SQL Server Express Edition":
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx

Or the "Compact Edition":
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx